# PHPMailer in localhost showing an error Called Mail() without being connected. how can I fix it?

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com"; // your GMail user name
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxx"; 
$mail->AddAddress("yourmail@yahoo.com"); // recipients email
$mail->FromName = "abc"; // readable name

$mail->Subject = "Sample Email";
$mail->Body    = "Here is the message you want to send to your friend."; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

> Mailer Error: The following From address failed: mymail@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected.

How can I fix it??

Comment: Try using port 587 instead  of 25 for smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an old example. Get the latest from GitHub.